# Make CRectTracker object top-most

Tags: c++, mfc, z-order, tracker

I have an MFC dialog application where the user can upload a photo and it will be displayed within the dialog. After they have uploaded an image they will be able select a region of this image and for this I am using the CRectTracker class. My problem however is that the tracker is currently being displayed behind the image.

What I have tried so far is:

- Googling how to set the z-order of the CRectTracker object, but cannot seem to find any documentation on it.
- Set the z-order of the image to the bottom using `SetWindowPos(&wndBottom,...)` but the tracker still appears behind the image.

I am using a Picture Control (type Bitmap) to display the image.

**EDIT:**
I draw the tracker in the `OnPaint()` method of my dialog class like this:

```
CPaintDC dc(this); 
m_tracker.Draw(&dc);
```

which is being called by `this->Invalidate();` in `OnLButtonDown` and `OnMouseMove` whenever I need to refresh the tracker:

```
void CTAB3::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if (m_tackerFlag)
    {
        int nHitTest;
        nHitTest = m_tracker.HitTest(point);

        if (nHitTest < 0)     // if the mouse down point is outside of the rect tracker
        {
            m_start = point;    // Record the start drawing point
            m_bDraw = TRUE;     // set m_bDraw (in handle funtion WM_MOUSEMOVE will test this to decide whether to draw)
        }
        else                    // if the mouse down point is inside of the rect tracker
        {
            m_tracker.Track(this, point, FALSE); // start drag the rect tracker
            this->Invalidate();               // make the window paint to refresh the track
        }
    }
    CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}


void CTAB3::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // m_bDraw is set to true in funtion OnLButtonDown and set to false in funtion OnLButtonDown
    // m_bDraw is use for testing if the mouse is moved along with the left button is pressed.
    if (m_bDraw)
    {
        m_tracker.m_rect.SetRect(m_start, point); // set the rect of rect tracker
        this->Invalidate();                      // make the window paint to refresh the rect
    }
    CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

**EDIT2:**
Based on @ConstantineGeorgiou comment I decided to keep trying to implement the tracker with the resize handles using `Track()` as this would be the preferred solution for my project. I finally managed to draw the tracker on top of the image, but I am not particularly happy with the solution I ended up with. Basically I moved the `Draw()` function to the mouse move handler, so that the tracker is drawn after the `OnPaint()` has drawn everything else on the dialog. If anyone has any suggestion on better ways to do this, I would be very grateful for any feedback.

This is how I implemented it with the `Draw()` in the `OnMouseMove()` handler:

```
//In the header file:
BOOL m_bDraw = FALSE
```

```
void CTAB3::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if (m_tackerFlag)
    {
        m_tracker.Track(this, point, FALSE); // start drag the rect tracker
        this->Invalidate();          
        m_bDraw = TRUE;
    }
    CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

```
void CTAB3::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if (m_bDraw)
    {
        //Draw tracker
        CDC* dc = GetDC();
        m_tracker.Draw(dc);
    }

    CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

```
BOOL CTAB3::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)
{
    if (m_tackerFlag)
    {
        if (pWnd == this && m_tracker.SetCursor(this, nHitTest))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return CDialogEx::OnSetCursor(pWnd, nHitTest, message);
}
```

```
void CTAB3::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    //m_tracker.Draw(&dc);
}
```

Comment: Not a z-order -related problem at all, as `CRectTracker` is not a window - you tried setting the z-order of the image-window to the bottom, obviously because you couldn't move the CRectTracker to the top. CRectTracker is drawn/painted on the drawing surface (device context) of another window (the image-window in your case).

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you, I think I see the problem now. I have edited the original post to show how I draw the tracker, but from what I understand I need to draw it on the device context of the picture control (image) instead of the dialog window, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the Picture Control's device context. The easiest way to get to it is to subclass the Picture Control (I assume, that's a [`CStatic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatic-class) control in MFC).

Comment: Could you explain a bit further? I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I have an photo editor with a cropping rectangle. While dragging, I directly draw the rectangle with a `DisplayCrop` call in `OnMouseMove` while the mouse is captured. The rectangle is drawn in `OnPaint` with a call to  `DisplayCrop` so it persists. Works very smoothly that way.

Comment: @lakeweb,  thanks for the suggestion! But what is `DisplayCrop`? I cannot seem to find any documentation on it

Comment: To subclass a control you provide your own implementation that derives from `CStatic`, add a class member of that type to whichever class represents the UI, and add a call to `DDX_Control` to your `DoDataExchange` implementation. The latter wires up the UI component with your C++ class. At that point you can respond to the Picture Control's `OnPaint` callback and mouse input messages. Don't forget to call into the base class implementation where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you @IInspectable, I have done as you suggested and subclassed CStatic and made my picture control an object of this class: `CMyStatic m_CalibrationPicture;`. Then wired up the picture control to the UI component: `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_PICTURE_CALIBRATION, m_CalibrationPicture);` However, now I am facing the problem of the image no longer being displayed, and I suspect that it is because the DC gets repainted every time `OnPaint()` is called and this "erases" my image.  I tried changing the `bErase` parameter of `Invalidate();` to FALSE, but still no image. Any other ways to fix this?

Comment: *"Don't forget to call the base class implementation"* - Did you?

Comment: I did not, I think see where I have gone wrong. I would have to find the base class (`CStatic`) code and copy the `OnPaint()` function (and potentially the other ones too) from there and then add any additional code from the tracker to that, is that correct? If that is the case where could I find the code for `CStatic`?

Comment: Hi, `DisplayCrop` is a member you would add. [Mine looks like this](https://pastebin.com/jYJarbpq). `HE_DRAGRECT_BRDR` is the width of the boarder.

Comment: Having no experience on using the `CRectTracker` class, I'm asking you are you sure you are using it the right way? Especially invalidating (and consequently repainting) the image in every mouse move looks like an unnecessary overhead to me. Actually I think you wouldn't even need to override `OnMouseMove()`, just `OnLButtonDown()` (call the `Track()` method); the CRectTracker's implementation should be able to handle the rest (mouse move, LBtnUp, ESC key etc) as per the documentation, and the `m_rect` member looks like it is intended for returning the selected rectangle, not setting it.

Comment: I did some testing and it seems like you are correct that I don't need the rest (mouse move, LBtnUp, ESC key etc) just the `OnLButtonDown()`. But the problem is that the tracker is only drawn while it is being moved (as a dotted line), when I release the left mouse button it displays nothing (the tracker is still there and I can keep moving it, it is just not being displayed). If I just put the `Draw()` function in my `OnLButtonDown()` I will have all the old rectangles displayed as well so I need a way to remove them and draw a new one every time I release the left mouse button.

Comment: Calling `Draw()` may or may not be needed according to what you are trying to do. Using `TrackRubberBand()` to track the selection generally does not require calling `Draw()`, the selection starts from the point originally clicked and continues to the point where the left button is released; during tracking it displays a selection rectangle. Using `Track()` generally does require calling `Draw()` though, as you need to display a selection originally, which can be modified using the resizing handles. Which method are you interested in?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou, you have a good point about the `TrackRubberBand()`. My application does not necessarily need the `Track()` functionality so I might try and use rubber band instead to get around the `Draw()` problems I am having. Thank you all so much for your inputs, they have been very useful.

Comment: Well, choosing one solution because the other one is harder to implement is not the right approach imo (unless it is extremely "expensive" or much more complicated or unreliable). The point is the project requirements or "specs". If all you want is be able to draw a selection (eg like in MS-Paint), the "rubber-band" solution is acceptable, if instead you think those resize handles would be nice, you should rather go with `Track()`. And it's not really much more complicated, it just requires one call to `Draw()`. In either case you could post some code snippets here for reviews and suggestions,